# Brazil 2002 first problem neater result?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Brazil's 2002 first problem basically asks to prove that for any positive integer n, there are n integers $m_1,m_2\dots m_n$ where $1\leq m_i\leq9$ such that $m_1^2+m_2^2+\ldots+m_n^2=a^2$ for some integer $a$. Can we find a non-constructive proof of this?

A constructive answer can be found at the following link: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2477647&sid=bb5c5686f0ea79b2dc13977706ffc9bd#p2477647

Comment: As for the title, I thought the solution give was pretty neat. $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ seems like a unique case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is non-constructive or valid, but for large enough $n$, you can take the square of any number 1 through 9, call it $a$, and find a sum of squares with digits $b_i$ (1 through 9) so $b_1^2 + b_2^2 + ... b_n^2 = a^2$. Then your number is $aaaa...(b_1 b_2 ... b_n) ...$ so that the number of $a$'s + groups of $b_1 b_2 ... b_n$ = a square number.

Comment: buth there can be no zeroes. So you can't always do that.

Comment: If the number is sufficiently long you should be able to. However I can't guarantee  solutions for 1 through 9 without specifically using the example given in the link